# Useful bountied answer removed

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I awarded a bounty on an answer to this question [seleniumbase (undetected Chrome driver): how to set request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494543/seleniumbase-undetected-chrome-driver-how-to-set-request-header) but the relevant answer has disappeared, presumably deleted for some unknown reason.

The answer was very useful as it discussed an approach, to an awkward problem, that was not shown elsewhere on the web.

Could it be restored please?

Comment: Answer *was* deleted by a Mod. @blackgreen. Perhaps they will comment

Comment: "It seems" the user answered and earned [multiple bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536363/gabriel-ramuglia?tab=bounties&sort=earned) that have deleted posts (10k rep link). I suspect that they have more posts as well that didn't earn then. I suspect that's there's more going on that just on that post.

Comment: It was an excellent answer and showed zero signs of AI involvement (to me, anyway).

Comment: There's is a least one indicator on those posts that suggests LLM (intentionally not shared).

Comment: It's probably easier if I write a new answer showing the relevant solution, isn't it.

Comment: After more searching, and finding more deleted content, I think it might be that all theirs post are copied from the website they own... This would also explain the LLM like behaviour I noticed.

Comment: Slightly alarmed by the fact that, immediately after I posted this, someone went in to the original question and silently downvoted everything in sight, including an answer from an innocent party!

Comment: Its is called the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2670892) - drawing attention to a question often results in extra up or down votes.

Comment: I get that, but not the blanket effect ... this meta question got downvoted at the same time, again silently.

Comment: I wouldn’t fixate in the “silently” part. Commenting while voting is not to be expected.

Comment: Someone has also "silently" upvoted your other question now too, @MandyShaw , are you concerned about that as well.?

Comment: Looking at the content from the author's website, as well, I suspect it's LLM generated. Prior to December 2022 the site had about 100 articles produced by different authors. Since then, over 1,000 have been generated (almost) all by the same individual and on some days the volume of content is insane. On 08 Jan 2024 the author of the bounty recieving answer posted 39 blog posts on their website... If it's not LLM, it's either multiple authors or plagiarism going on there.

Comment: Even the answer that wasn’t deleted has some LLM elements which I won’t specify either.

Comment: “Could it be replaced please?” - If it was generated by an LLM, it absolutely will NOT, be restored.

Comment: That's fine, thank you everyone for your help, I will add the missing solution as an answer myself.

Comment: And I don't have a problem with silent down (or up) votes when they don't all turn up at once! That was what I found peculiar.

Comment: The non-deleted, non-bountied, downvoted answer from "Mark" looks *blatantly* ChatGPT generated to me (again, indicators deliberately not shared).

Comment: That'll be why I felt like I was talking into the void with them, then ... it never even occurred to me. Doh.